# near-sdk-rs: view call fails trying to call to attached_deposit, but nothing in the contract seems to be looking at the attached_deposit

Tags: nearprotocol

I have the following method in my contract:

```
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, PanicOnDefault)]
pub struct MyContract {
    ...,
}   

#[near_bindgen]
impl MyContract {
    ...
    pub fn is_account_whitelisted(account_id: &AccountId) -> bool {
        Self::account_task_ordinals_map().contains_key(account_id)
    }

    fn account_task_ordinals_map() -> LookupMap<AccountId, Option<u32>> {
        LookupMap::new(b"o".to_vec())
    }
    ...
}
```

`is_account_whitelisted` is intended to be used as a view method. I then later use it from near-api-js in the following way:

```
    window.contract = await near.loadContract(nearConfig.contractName, {
        viewMethods: ['is_account_whitelisted', ...],
        changeMethods: [...],
        sender: window.walletAccount.getAccountId()
    });
    ...
    window.contract.is_account_whitelisted({'account_id': window.walletAccount.getAccountId()}).then(m => console.log(m));
```

and it fails with

```
...
FunctionCallError(HostError(ProhibitedInView { method_name: "attached_deposit" })).
{
  "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(ProhibitedInView { method_name: \"attached_deposit\" }))",
...
```

Do I need to annotate the method in some way, am I not calling it right, or is there something that I use in the method that causes the call to the `attached_deposit`?

Comment: It looks like a `near-sdk` bug. Because it treats `is_account_whitelisted(account_id: &AccountId)` as non-view method for some reason which does a check for the attached deposit. But the attached deposit call is prohibited at the runtime during view calls.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the Evgeny's comment, I found out that presently a method is only considered a view method if it has a immutable self as the first argument. Here's the link to the relevant code in near-sdk-rs:

https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/18b8f8f3b672bfb422ff83a5138395f7e24dd70d/near-sdk-core/src/info_extractor/attr_sig_info.rs#L109

It is likely to be fixed soon, but in the meantime the way to address it is to add the immutable self as the first argument.